# noquote doesn't output after Shiny terminates

Tags: r, shiny

Below is snippit of shiny code. (Entire R script is [here](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R)) It uses `print`, but it would print on console with quotes AFTER shiny exits.

```
CustomPal <- function(new_pal){
      ...
      server = function(input,output,session){
      ...
        observeEvent(input$action, {
            ...
            print("Colors stored in variable cherrypickedpalette")
            ...
          }#end !is.null(outputdata)
          ...
}
```

I replaced it with `noquote` so the string isn't surrounded with quotes. Unfortunately the string doesn't print.

How to fix?

```
CustomPal <- function(new_pal){
      ...
      server = function(input,output,session){
      ...
        observeEvent(input$action, {
            ...
            noquote("Colors stored in variable cherrypickedpalette")
            ...
          }#end !is.null(outputdata)
          ...
}
```

Comment: `noquote()` doesn't print anything. It just wraps a special class around a string so it doesn't print with quotes. You'd have to do `print(noquote("..."))` to get the value to print. That's still not going to change _when_ it prints, however. Is that the thing you are really trying to change?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I wish to print a string without quotes. Your `print(noquote("..."))` works. Thank you!